# Retrieving the results from a table using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy

How can I print the results returned by 
session.query(User.name).filter(User.gender != 'male')

This will return all the male candidates in the table. I want to print name of each candidate seperately.
Do I need to include a for loop for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [official documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/tutorial.html#querying)

```
>>> for instance in session.query(User).order_by(User.id): 
...     print instance.name, instance.fullname
ed Ed Jones
wendy Wendy Williams
mary Mary Contrary
fred Fred Flinstone
```